# Many-to-many without a extra table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `operation` and `source` in `mysql` database.

In `operation` I have 10 rows(possibility) and in `source` just 3 rows(possibility) and between them there is a `many-to-many` relationship.
**Question**: Is it necessary to add this extra table or just add a foreign key of `source` in `operation`.

`operation` can be subscribe request, subscribe enabled , subscribe disabled , subscribe canceled , payment ok , subscribe deal ok , subscribe start.

`source` can be from internet , from agent

there is common operations and independent operations from source.

the operaion `subscribe enabled` can be done from internet subscribe or from agent subscribe  and operation : `subscribe deal ok` can be just from agent and `subscribe request` can be just from internet.

Comment: How are you referencing `operation` in `source`? Just having a fkey on `operation` to the id of `source` *will not be sufficient* if it actually is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Can you provide a sample or mock up of the data you are working with? What would you intend to key it off of? Also, would this actually be better as one table with all of your combinations?

Comment: @TZHX i need just the information from `operation` ... in `source` it's not a problem to reference `operation`

Comment: @gmiley in just one table ? i will think to see

Comment: I mean is there some identity column in `source` that already exists in `operation`? Like I said, some sample data of both tables and your intended results would be of tremendous help when asking a question like this. If this is new design work/re-work, then redoing the tables as one table containing all combinations would probably be best. if this is pre-existing and cannot be changed, then a join table will probably be required.

Comment: @gmiley i add a sample of data

Answer (score 7):

In a relational database you need 3 tables to make a many to many relationship. Two containing the primary keys and the join table. There's no other way.

Comment: Technically, you can have many-to-many relationship just in a single table, when database in non-normalized i.e. lots of redundant data.

Answer (score 7):

For the short and brief answer, normally, with an rdbms like mysql, where only one-to-many relations are supported, you need a 3rd (junction, or cross-reference) table to implement a many-to-many relation between two entities.

**But....**

Since you don't have too many records, you can map your many-to-many relation between `source` and `operation` with *just one additional column* in `source` and without redundant data storage. However, you may possibly loose some performance (e.g.: less powerful indexes) and definitely make your life harder working with these tables...

The trick is to use specific binary values as primary key values in your `operation` table, and add an integer column to the `source` table where you use its bits to map the relations. So one bit of this column describes one relation between the actual source record and the corresponding operation record.

For your sample `operation` table, you can create a table with a pri key of a `bit` type, with a size equal to your estimated number of rows. You say that you are going to have ~10 rows, so use `bit(10)` as data type. Since, mysql would store int on 4 bytes, you don't loose on the storage size here (instead, compared to int, you may actually win some, but it is really a matter of how the dbe is able to compress the records. actually, you could simply use int as well, if you wish.)

```
create table operation (id bit(10) primary key, title varchar(50));

insert into operation values (b'0', 'none');
insert into operation values (b'1', 'subscribe request');
insert into operation values (b'10', 'subscribe enabled');
insert into operation values (b'100', 'subscribe disabled');
insert into operation values (b'1000', 'subscribe canceled');
insert into operation values (b'10000', 'payment ok');
insert into operation values (b'100000', 'subscribe deal ok');
insert into operation values (b'1000000', 'subscribe start');
```

Now, suppose that you have the following in your source table:

```
create table source (id int primary key, value int, operations bit(10));

insert into source values (1, 1, b'0');
insert into source values (2, 2, b'1'); -- refers to subscribe request
insert into source values (3, 3, b'10'); -- refers to subscribe enabled
insert into source values (4, 4, b'10011'); -- refers to payment ok, subscribe request, subscribe enabled
insert into source values (5, 5, b'1110011'); -- refers to subscribe deal ok, subscribe start, payment ok, subscribe request, subscribe enabled
```

Now, if you want *to select all the relations*, join these two tables as follows:

```
select source.id, operation.title
from source
join operation
  on (source.operations & operation.id);

id  operation.title
2   subscribe request
4   subscribe request
5   subscribe request
3   subscribe enabled
4   subscribe enabled
5   subscribe enabled
4   payment ok
5   payment ok
5   subscribe deal ok
5   subscribe start
```

If you want *to add a new relation*, you may take advantage of the [on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause of insert, so you don't have to worry about existing relations:

```
insert into source (id,value,operations)
   values (2,2,(select id from operation where title = 'subscribe start'))
on duplicate key update operations = operations
   | (select id from operation where title = 'subscribe start');
```

If you want *to delete a relation*:

```
update source set operations = operations
   & ~(select id from operation where title = 'subscribe start') where source.id=2;
```

All in all, it is not a nice, but a possible way to map your many-to-many relation to just two tables.

Comment: thanks for your answer i will think about it and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your question can have many answers depending on your real needs.

In fact, in the described situation, you can have just one table "operation" with a `source` column defined as a MySQL `SET` type. You will then be able to select 0 to many sources for each opeartion.

You might then alter your table operation to set a source column

```
  ALTER TABLE operation ADD source SET('from internet', 'from agent');
```

If you really need to have two tables (let suppose your "source" table contain other fields), you should have a third table to make the relation between them.

But, technically, there are situations where, for performance reasons for instance, you could prefer to store your foreign keys in a varchar() field of one of the table, with a coma delimitor, and use PHP to retrieve the data. But it's not the good way of doing it, although it *is* possible as long as your retrieval of the data is done in one only direction, and you're really sure what you're doing.

For instance, in this "hacky-way", you can imagine an ActiveRecord-like PHP class, where you might wish to retrieve your sources with a method like this

```
 public function getSources() {
    private $_sources;
    if (!isset($this->_sources)) {
        $this->_sources=DBSource::findByPks(explode(",", $this->sources));
    }
    return $this->_sources;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i will think about it and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the problem you describe, it seems you don't necessarily have a many-to-many relationship as both '*source*' and '*operation*' are enumerations ( a constant set of values ). Therefore, '*source*' and '*operation*' do not act as a table but as a data type (i.e. a column type).

You might take a look to [Enums in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html) and to create your own '*source*' and '*operation*' enum and place them into a table that keeps that "virtual many-to-many relation".

Please, keep in mind that for the solution I am proposing I am assuming that '*source*' and '*operation*' have a constant and known set of values. In case that was not true, then you would get into trouble as you would have a non-normalized database.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you take most simple approach to the problem, it is usually the best one. Use many to many relationship only when it is really needed.

You wrote:

> in source just 3 rows(possibility)
>
> source can be from internet , from agent

Those are only two options.

Why not have `source` like this:

1. from internet
2. from agent
3. from internet & agent

Basically if you are pretty sure that the set of `source`s will not grow you can hardcode all variants. It gets optimized this way but you loose flexibility. Something similar to @lp_ 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that in the source table there are at maximum 3 rows you can map the relationship as many to 3 (instead of many to many) with operation table like the following

```
operation
---------
id_source_1
id_source_2
id_source_3
```

If you don't know how many rows there are in source you need a third table, because a many to many relationship can be mapped only with a third table.